# Tile 3 does not work on struts2

Tags: struts2, tiles, struts2-tiles-plugin

I am trying to use Tile plugin in my struts2 application, but I am receiving the following error,

"Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener. Please see server.log for more details."

I have the following jar files:

```
tiles-api-3.0.1.jar
tiles-autotag-core-runtime-1.1.0.jar
tiles-compat-3.0.1.jar
tiles-core-3.0.1.jar
tiles-el-3.0.1.jar
tiles-extras-3.0.1.jar
tiles-freemarker-3.0.1.jar
tiles-jsp-3.0.1.jar
tiles-mvel-3.0.1.jar
tiles-ognl-3.0.1.jar
tiles-request-api-1.0.1.jar
tiles-request-freemarker-1.0.1.jar
tiles-request-jsp-1.0.1.jar
tiles-request-mustache-1.0.1.jar
tiles-request-servlet-1.0.1.jar
tiles-request-servlet-wildcard-1.0.1.jar
tiles-request-velocity-1.0.1.jar
tiles-servlet-3.0.1.jar
tiles-template-3.0.1.jar
tiles-velocity-3.0.1.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-digester-2.0.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
        </result-types>
        <action name="register">
            <result type="tiles">register</result>
        </action>
    </package>


</struts>
```

My struts library files

```
Struts 2.3.4 Core Libraries - xwork-core-2.3.4.jar
Struts 2.3.4 Core Libraries - struts2-core-2.3.4.jar
Struts 2.3.4 Core Libraries - struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.4.jar
Struts 2.3.4 Core Libraries - ognl-3.0.5.jar
Struts 2.3.4 Core Libraries - javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
Struts 2.3.4 Core Libraries - freemarker-2.3.19.jar
Struts 2.3.4 Core Libraries - commons-lang3-3.1.jar
Struts 2.3.4 Core Libraries - commons-io-2.0.1.jar
Struts 2.3.4 Core Libraries - commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
Struts 2.3.4 Core Libraries - asm-tree-3.3.jar
Struts 2.3.4 Core Libraries - asm-commons-3.3.jar
Struts 2.3.4 Core Libraries - asm-3.3.jar
```

Comment: Have you added the new struts2-tiles3 plugin? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Tiles+3+Plugin how are you managing dependencies, maven?

Comment: I also see you have the conventions plugin in place... once you get basic functionality working let me know, I might suggest a method to tie struts2 into conventions.

Comment: @Quaternion, I have downloaded and added the struts2-tiles-plugin-2.2.3.1.jar but it does not work yet.

Comment: Well download netbeans and follow this step by step guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718418/struts2-netbeans-7, which will get all the resources using maven... it will download all the required jars... then you can take the jars and put them into your own project. You'll also very quickly realize why maven is so awesome.

Comment: Oh the above does not address adding that particular plugin but the first link spells out the maven co-ordinates and the second link explains how to use them. You'll easily figure it out.

Comment: @Quaternion, yes I tried but got confused as it found many files except the one I am looking for.

Comment: The jars that maven obtains are all dependencies... what is confusing? If you are missing any, your program will not work.

Comment: If it is still not working I'll supply a dump of all dependencies in a minimal struts2 + tiles3 _ struts2-conventions-plugin application...